# silverlight (or WPF) dependecyProperty without backing field - wrapper only

Tags: c#, wpf, silverlight, xaml

I have custom control (or templated control)  which encapsulates rich edit control and many icon bars. That control has a Content property. I need to operate with this Content property directly from xaml using my new control:

```
<myCustomRichEditWithIconBars Content="{Binding file,
                                        Converter={StaticResource ...}}" />

 ...
```

Reason?

This rich edit control content can be very large file. I don't want to have it stored twice.

So I need only propagate this Content property to myCustomRichEditWithIconBars.

Can you help me with this please?

Thank you very much.

Tom

Answer (score 0):

I'd advise against it.

This idea will have a few drawbacks:

1. You'll be limited to either one way binding, or be forced to save
   whenever the binding updates.
2. Your file operations will be activated when the control loads, and
   you'll have no external control over file interactions.
3. You are stuck handling read write exceptions in your converter, and they only other place that could catch it would be your generic unhandled exceptions handler. Not fun.
4. If you have multiple copies of your control, you have multiple objects responsible for controlling read-write, and you'd be forced to close the file.

I'd consider having code-behind expose the rich text field, or expose a property that updates the rich text field. You'd have far more control over it that way. And you'd be able to control file operations when you want to, and not whenever a converter intervenes.

If you must...

First you have the binding wrong. You don't bind from the outside of the control, because you'd still have two copies. One copy would be the content of your control, the other copy would be the rich text control's copy. You bind between a property on your control and the content property on the rich text control. There you use a converter.

You'll need to change it so your custom control's content is actually a string which is the filepath, and the converter is between your inner rich text and wrapped control.

```
public class myCustomRichEditWithIconBars
{
    public override void OnApplyTemplate() 
    {
        // get part and store in _textField; 
        // bind rich text content field to filepath using converter.
        // this can be done in the xaml of your control too.
    }
    public String filePath {...}
    private RichText _textField {...}
}
```

The converter will open the filepath and read the file and return the file's contents, and when it converts back it will save the file from the rich text's content.

```
public class myConverter : IValueConverter
{
    Convert(...)
    {
        var filePath = (String)value;
        // read file, return what goes into the rich text field.
    }
    ConvertBack(...)
    {
        var richText = // the data from the field.
        // save into file.
    }
}
```

Comment: Hello Lee, Thank you very much for very detailed answer. I should provide you with a more details about my situation. I am sorry, I had to do that in my first post. I am using WCF service working with files like a byte[]. The converter should converts formats not from file path but between formats (RTF, html, word -> richedit special format). May be I should try something like: <myrichedit><myrichedit.richedit content="{binding willbehere, converter={too}}" /></myrichedit> What do you think? Thank you very much. Tom

Comment: @Tom It's best if you don't expose the internal richedit, and you use a binding in your template for the control. But if you have to, that might work. Try it and let us know. At minimum make the richedit readonly. The key is to make sure you only have one binding with one converter, and convert between the data formats.

Comment: No go. This was stupid.  <myrichedit><myrichedit.richedit content="{binding willbehere, converter={too}}" /></myrichedit> It is not possible to specify Content (or any other) property in inner tag.

Comment: @Tom Then you don't need a converter. Use INotifyPropertyChanged. Your property on your main control converts and sets the value for the rich text, then listen for changes on the rich text property and raise the PropertyChanged event.